# Auto "Counting" using letters instead of numbers

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that I to which I need to add counting.  I know how to do this with numbers, but I have a sub group that I want to list in the order in which they *happen* to appear (from the filter/sort setting of the report) using letters incrementing up automatically (a,b,c,d . . .).  How would I do this?

Comment: Sorry, this is in an Access Report

Comment: Please update your question with additional details, what have you tried?

Comment: i'd use a number on the back end and leverage Char() to turn it into letters. if you need more than 26 make a custom function with mod.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.asciitable.com/ and you will need to convert to ascii and back.  You need to be using something like a CHAR or CHR to loop through from 65-91 and 97-122.  However, you may need to be careful of punctuation as they will not work.

Comment: I have created a  text box in the Design area of the report and then tried to use the {Control Source =1} and {Running Sum "Over Group} Function of the properties, but substituting a beginning letter such as "a" for the number.  It allowed this to save, but that only prints an "a" in every box.

Comment: OK, I have successfully gotten "Chr(97)" to place an "a" in the box by placing this in the "Control Source" of the Property for the text box.  Now, how to increment the ascii number by on for each new line . . .  Should be simple, but nothing I do increments the number.  Adding "+1" only makes the letter appear as a "b" in ALL the boxes . . . Frustrated!!  Thanks for any help anyone can offer . . .